# Extract CDATA from an element using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

Input:(XML)

```
<A1Result xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <![CDATA[
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <ABCD_XML_DATA>
        <Header>
            <MessageId>AGDMY1323292534488</MessageId>
        </Header>
    </ABCD_XML_DATA>
    ]]>
</A1Result>
```

I need this output using xsl:

```
<ABCD_XML_DATA>
    <Header>
        <MessageId>AGDMY1323292534488</MessageId>
    </Header>
</ABCD_XML_DATA>
```

additional info, my i/p & o/p are written in/to varibales.

i tried this,

```
<xsl:variable name="Data"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$A1Result" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> 
</xsl:variable>
```

please suggest how to achieve this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

finally figured out, the original answer from Borodin(below) also works. I had to parse the i/p, for my processor to recognize.

(i am using dp xsl processor, so the name space dp); i was trying the same thing yesterday with no luck; i had to parse it to work.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="dp:parse(dp:variable('var://context/saved/MyRes')//*[local-name()='A1Result'])" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

where, 'var://context/saved/MyRes', has the input xml from question.

Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

Your source XML is not well-formed because you can't have an XML declaration after the opening tag of the root element.

Assuming this declaration should be moved to the top of the file, you can write an XSLT transform that use the `text` output method to produce what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="A1Result"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<ABCD_XML_DATA>
    <Header>
        <MessageId>AGDMY1323292534488</MessageId>
    </Header>
</ABCD_XML_DATA>
```

---

**Update**

If you want to remove the XML declaration from the CDATA then the best you can do is use

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(A1Result, '?>')"/>
```

Comment: also, input is saved in a varibale. i cannot have match as root.

Comment: @user2395396: I've updated my answer to deal with your first comment. Are you now saying that the entire XML document an XSLT variable value?

Comment: yes. and i am trying to save it again in a varibale. more info added in question.

Comment: @Borodin This isn't right. Anything other than `]]>` is allowed in CDATA - see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect "Within a CDATA section, only the CDEnd string is recognized as markup, so that left angle brackets and ampersands may occur in their literal form; they need not (and cannot) be escaped using " &lt; " and " &amp; ". CDATA sections cannot nest. "

Comment: @peter.murray.rust: I'm sorry, what isn't right? I don't see that what you have quoted conflicts with anything I have written.

Comment: Nothing has special meaning in a CDATA section expect `]]>` The ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` will be ignored by an XML parser other than to capture the characters. Have you parsed the OP's source XML and got an Exception? (BTW the question is not "invalid" but whether the OP's XML is "well-formed". But I will parse it

Comment: My test (using XOM parser) reads the XML without errors (and XOM is a very compliant parser). If you still doubt my interpretation we can open it as an SO question!

Comment: As a side note, the line that you are calling a "processing instruction" is an XML declaration, not a processing instruction.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust: The question has been modified because of my comment above, and is now OK. The original had the XML declaration outside the CDATA. By all means open a question if you wish.

Comment: @Borodin This is the problem of commenting on a continually edited question and keeping the comments in sync! So we are agreed. The version (4) is wellformed XML and it's even possible the OP could have intended the XML declaration to be within the CDATA section.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust: Since that is where he has put it in his question I have to assume that that is where it is in his data. However I think you were a little hasty with your criticism, given that the very first comment here is from the OP, saying *"i corrected the input(xml is part of cdata)"* Is the downvote yours? I have no other major detractors.

Comment: Borodin & Peter, after all the above discussion, not sure i got the answer ? all my code is in 1 xsl file in variables(i/p & o/p). i tried to extract the cdata to a o/p varibale, but noluck; I am sure if the input is passed as a new context, i can definetly extract what i need. But my requirement is to read the input data from a varibale and write the above o/p to vairable.